# Как сделать тему в джанго общедоступной для других пользователей, в том числе не прошедших аутенфикацию?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Topic(models.Model):
    """Тема, которую изучает пользователь"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name = 'User', related_name='topics', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)


    def __str__(self):
        """Возвращает строковое представление модели."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Информация, изученная пользователем по теме."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
 
    def __str__(self):
        """Возвращает строковое представление модели."""
        if len(self.text) >= 51:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Topic, Entry

from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """Домашняя страница приложения Learning Log"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

@login_required
def topics(request):
    """Вывоит список всех тем"""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Выводит одну тему и все ее записи"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    # Проверка того, что тема принадлежит текущему пользователю
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """Определяет новую тему"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Данные не отправлялись, создать пустую форму
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # Отправлены данные POST, обработать данные
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Добавляет новую запись по конкретной теме."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    check_topic_owner(topic, request)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Данные не отправлялись; создается пустая форма.
        form = EntryForm()        
    else:
        # Отправлены данные POST; обработать данные.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                args=[topic_id]))
    
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Редактирует существущую запись"""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    check_topic_owner(topic, request)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # исходный запрос, форма заполняется текущими данными записи
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        # Отправка данных 'POST', обработать данные
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)

def check_topic_owner(topic, request):
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

Убери декоратор @login_required и данное условие **if topic.owner != request.user:
raise Http404**

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Выводит одну тему и все ее записи"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    # Проверка того, что тема принадлежит текущему пользователю
   
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```